# Como limitar downloads do Firebase Storage a uma certa quantidade máxima por período de tempo por usuário?

Tags: android, firebase

Gostaria de saber como posso limitar a demanda de download no meu aplicativo,20 por hora...
Obs. uso o firebase , sem login, a única forma que eu reconheço um usuário e com `id de anúncio do google` o aplicativo só funciona com conexão com a internet.

**Atualização**
Se o cliente faz 10 downloads e volta depois de 1 hora o ideal seria que zera-se a contagem.

Este é o código que uso para download:

```
 if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                    Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

                final String STORAGE = mChat = getIntent().getExtras().getString("storage");

                progress = ProgressDialog.show(MinhaActivity.this, "Download...",
                        "Aguarde...", true);
                FirebaseStorage mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                StorageReference storageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("MY_DB").child(STORAGE).child(down+".mp3");

                File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                final File localFile = new File(sdCardDirectory.getPath()+"/Audio",down+".mp3");


                storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(Minhactivity.this,"Salvo em "+localFile.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progress.dismiss();

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    }
                });


            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MinhaActivity.this,"Você está sem Cartão de memória",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Agradeço a atenção de todos envolvidos desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode ter uma uma lista de usuários (no seu caso, ids de anúncio) e, associado a cada usuário, uma lista de timestamps dos momentos nos quais foi feito cada download.

Antes de inicializar um download, pegue os últimos 20 e veja se todos estão dentro de um intervalo de duas horas (basta subtrair o mais recente pelo mais antigo e ver se o intervalo é menor ou igual a duas horas). Se estiverem, não autorize o download. Se não estiverem, acrescente o timestamp atual à lista e autorize o download.

Comment: Entendi a lógica cara,mais tenho duvidas, qual é o resultado em timeStamp para 1 hora... eu  havia pensado em usar o timeStamp mais não tenho certeza se sempre dará certo o calculo.

Comment: dei uma estudada aqui no timeStamp tudo certo agora, obrigado!

Comment: Por nada. Espero que dê certo aí.